# How to prove that a very large number is not prime

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, contest-math

I'm solving few math problems for an upcoming math contest .

I am stuck with a short problem, where I have to prove that $A$ is **not** prime .

$$A = 100\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 000\ 001$$

$A$ is not a binary number. It's a decimal one.

I've tried to rewrite like this:

$$ A = 1 \times 10^{20} + 1 $$

But what can I do with that . I can't use GCD since it would a very long time to finish it and Obviously this isn't the point from this problem .

Comment: Which is it? $10^{20}+1$ or $10^{21}+1$?

Comment: Natural numbers can be represented in binary too. The correct way would be to say 'this is a decimal representation of A, not a binary representation'

Comment: Looks like $10^{21}+1$, divisible by $11$.

Comment: $10^{20}+1$ has the factor $10001$, $10^{21}+1$ is even easier it has many factors (including $7,11,13$).

Comment: For positive odd $n$, $y+1$ is a factor of $y^n+1$. So $x^4+1$ is a factor of $(x^4)^5+1$, and $x+1$ is a factor of $x^{21}+1$.

Comment: First it's  $10^{20}$ , second I already know that it's not prime. But I need a way that it's not one . @almagest how did you find 10001 is a factor of A ?

Comment: @DeltaWeb I suppose he used $X^4+1\mid X^{20}+1$ (or even $X+1\mid X^5+1$)

Comment: @DeltaWeb If its $10^{20}+1$ then please edit the definition A=1000000000000000000001 which gives it as $10^{21}+1$.

Comment: @peterwhy Can you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @piepi By the [Linear Factor Test](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1198902/242) $\ y - a\ $ is a factor of a polynomial $f(y)$ iff $f(a) = 0.$ Above is the special case $\,a=-1\,$ and $\,f(y) = y^n+1,\ n\,$ odd.

Comment: @piepi Also consider this geometric series (for odd $n$) $$\begin{align*}
1 -x + x^2-x^3+\cdots + x^{n-1} &= \frac{(-x)^n-1}{-x-1}\\
(x+1)(1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots + x^{n-1}) &= x^n+1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That is not a very large number. It is _tiny_ compared to the numbers that can be routinely checked for primality these days.

Comment: Well just an addition: A number $x$ is prime if $\pi(x+1)-\pi(x)$ is $0$ or $1$. Here $\pi$ is the prime counting function.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

We have the number $10^{20}+1$. Whenever we have something in this kind of form, we need to find an odd factor of the exponent. In this case $5 \mid 20$, so we can use $5$ as the factor.

Now, we can say $10^{20}+1=(10^4)^5+1$. How does this help us? Well, if we say that $x=10^4$, we have the polynomial $x^5+1$. This polynomial has $-1$ as a zero, meaning $(x+1) \mid (x^5+1)$. Substituting $x=10^4$ back into this statement, we get $(10^4+1) \mid ((10^4)^5+1)=(10^{20}+1)$. Thus, $10^4+1$ is a factor of $10^{20}+1$, so the number is composite.

Notice how the factor had to be odd. Otherwise, if we have an even factor $n$, then $x^n+1$ would not have had $-1$ as a zero. This is a very common technique in math competitions that I have used several times before, so it will come in handy.

Comment: Very smart !, does this works too if for every number with the form $10^n + a$ . "I know that n has to be odd"

Comment: It works for $10^n+1$ where $n$ is not a power of $2$ (meaning that $n$ has an odd factor). Also, $10^n-1$ for any integer $n$ is composite because it has $9=3^2$ as a factor. There are also other forms of $10^n+a$ for integers $n, a$ where the number is always composite that can be found by converting the number into some polynomial form.

Comment: @DeltaWeb Also for numbers in the form $10^n-a^n$, and $a^n$ is a perfect $n$th power number. In this case, $n$ can be odd or even, and $a$ can be positive or negative, but $10-a\ne 1$. E.g. $100-9$ is divisible by $7$, and $1000-(-27)$ is divisible by $13$.

Comment: The case where this does not work, when $10^n+1$ has an exponent $n=2^m$, is called a generalized Fermat number (GFN) of base 10. Here it is not known if infinitely many such numbers are prime (it is conjectured that only $11$ ($2^m=2^0$) and $101$ ($2^m=2^1$) are primes). The page [GFN10 factoring status](http://www.prothsearch.net/GFN10.html) lists known factors of these numbers. The notation $F_m(10) = 10^{2^m}+1$ is used there. See also [Wikipedia: Fermat number § Generalized Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_numbers).

Comment: I don’t think it’s immediately obvious to the reader that dividing an integer polynomial by $(x + n)$ gives another integer polynomial (I know it’s true, but maybe it should be clarified).

Comment: @samhocevar Yes. One can also make the factorization explicit. Then it is clear that the quotient is an integer polynomial as well, and from the alternating nature of it we also see why it works only for an odd exponent. Here it is: $x^5+1=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$.

Answer (score 5):

$x^5+1 = (x+1)(x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)$  (and this will work for any odd power.
replace $x$ with $10^4$

$10^4+1$ divides $10^{20}+1$